# Varnish 4 add ban on vcl_backend_response with some specific header

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have an Restful API with Varnish cache server over and I want to ban a specific endpoint from the backend, through some http headers.

To be more specific I will give an example:

- I have updated an entity with some data, like: (PUT) /order/12345/delivery
- The response after the update it has an http header with the full entity endpoint to be banned: X-Cache-Ban: /order/12345/*

It is possible to add a ban from VCL based on that header from backend?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the PUT through Varnish the only way that this content can be modified? If not, I would consider instead going the wrote of having your application server actually submit the BAN request to the frontend when it detects that the object graph will change.